# Error related "undefined" is not valid JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, parsing

Hi Team I was working on social media app.i was testing my login page functionality. then i encountered error from screenshot which i attached for you reference.Please help me to fix this i am stuck.

[image: screenshot of error]

```
import axios from "axios";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null
    );

    console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    const login = async (inputs) => {
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/login", inputs, {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        setCurrentUser(res.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(currentUser));
    }, [currentUser]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, login }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse json on some thing that is undefined

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
```

that line when user is not in local storage is the same as

```
JSON.parse(undefined)
```

to fix this issue break it into 2 seperate lines

```
const storedUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(storedUser ? JSON.parse(user) : null);
```